# CSS: how to set the fixed width of the content regarding to the browser screen

Tags: html, css, width

I am new to CSS and HTML and I am pretty lost with this one. I would like to have a screen divided to two halves, while one of them has width equaled to 50% of maximized browser screen. While the other one will be flexible. So when you set the browser width to half, one of the contents will be fully visible, while the other one will be completely hidden. Of course I want this to be same for every resolution out there.

Same as foursquare: https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=New%20York%2C%20NY%2C%20United%20States&nearGeoId=72057594043056517 (maps is being hidden, and bars info is not affected until browser's width is less than 50%).

Here's the sample:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

/*width must be 50% of browser's maximum width, same as bars on foursquare*/

.lefthalf {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; 
}

/*width is between 0-50% of browser's maximum width, same as map on foursquare*/

.righthalf {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lefthalf"></div>
<div class="righthalf"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with the **Flexbox**:

```css
html, body { /* modified */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; /* recommended */
}

body {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline by default */
}

.lefthalf {
  /*float: left;*/
  background: black;
  flex: 0 0 750px; /* adjust to your needs / doesn't grow nor shrink with the initial width of 750px */
  /*height: 100%;*/
  overflow-x: auto; /* optional / enables horizontal scrolling if the content is wider than 750px (in this case) */
}

.righthalf {
  /*float: right;*/
  background: red;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*width: 50%;*/
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining horizontal space */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  .lefthalf {flex: 3} /* always three times wider than the .righthalf between 601px and 1000px screen width */
  .righthalf {flex: 1}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { /* adjust to your needs */
  body {
    flex-direction: column; /* recommended / stacks children vertically */
  }
  .lefthalf,
  .righthalf {
    flex: 1; /* optional & recommended / each takes half of the body height */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="lefthalf"></div>
<div class="righthalf"></div>
```

The `.lefthalf` needs to have a static `width` in `px`, it won't work with the defined `50%` or `50vw` because its `width` will change according to the browsers `width`.

Comment: thank you very much. The vertical stacking is really great and I will use it in my project.